# power bi year over year comparison and line chart

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, powerquery, linechart

I want a custom table/matrix in power bi displaying the year over year data and also a line chart displaying the same. i have all the year information in one column i.e both 2018 and 2019 data in one column. I want to perform an aggregate operation on another column and make the comparison for each of the month in the previous year

[The checkout date column has all the date information for both years. The caring attitude column has the data for which i want to perform aggregation based on month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHfiY.png)

[This is how i want the data to be displayed in the power bi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5sqh.png)

[This is the line chart i want. Year over Year comparison of those values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vac1D.png)

[In Excel I manually add the goal values in the rows and then create a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFx9X.png)

Comment: YoY measure you can create it with Quick Measures.Then you just have to drag and drop the date and measure to visuals.

Answer (score 0):

*for the former you just need to have date(years) as your rows date(months) as columns and caring attitude of staff as your values(this need to be done in a matrix visual and date should have hierarchy).
* for the latter date(months) as axis, date(years) as legend and caring attitude of staff as your values(for line chart).

Comment: Thanks sanjeev. Thank worked. I have upvoted you comment but it wont display as i am new to stackoverflow and i have less than 15 reputation.
And also how can I add a goal line to the graph? As you can see in the picture there is a green line which indicates goal. The goal value is just a manual value which I need to set and is not based on any calculation in the dataset. How can i add it?

Comment: You can check the fourth link. I manually add the goal values for all the months and create a graph. How to achieve the same in Power Bi?

Comment: no problem, you can upvote it later ;)..... just click on new measure assign a value and add it in your graph and or matrix!for ex: new measure=85 but for a graph you can also add a constant line from Analytics tab.

Comment: When i added the new measure to values of the matrix, it displays the data in a different format. Not in the way i want it to be displayed.

Comment: if you mean it to be 85.0 instead of 85 then just edit your measure.

Comment: by format i meant this. it splits up the goal value like this (https://drive.google.com/file/d/17b0iYZL6n3AnwA_ynDzyefkekXsobXhV/view) . I want it as just one row at the bottom , like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFx9X.png

Comment: i guess, it can't be done. you can very well put it as a new question, there could be someone who might help.